# Insert data in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am on  `php 5.6` using `WAMP` and want to insert a document into MongoDB using PHP. I am doing it in this way:

```
<?php

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

   $con = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
   echo "successfully";

   $db = $con->selectDatabase('DB');
   echo "Selected";

   $col = $db->selectCollection('myCol');
   $document = array( 
      "name" => "Deny", 
      "password" => "1234"
   );

   $col->insert($document);
   echo "successfully";

   ?>
```

But it is giving the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Collection::insert() in C:\wamp64\www...

I have read http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php and when I use the same insert function, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using this lib http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/index.html ?

Comment: @kcp Any installation page link?

Comment: @kcp Is it this one? `https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library`

Comment: Yes it is this one.

Comment: @kcp I have run the command `composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"` but what about .zip files?

Comment: @kcp Can you help?

Comment: Do you have mongodb driver installed ?

Comment: @kcp Resp. Problem is resolved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084561/install-phpmongo-drivers-on-windows

Comment: Its a bit late but you can find complete php mongodb tutorial here https://programmerblog.net/php-mongodb-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **MongoDB\Client** use **MongoClient** .

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install MongoClient library:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Comment: This extension is deprecated, better to use this: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/index.html

Comment: Can you share installation page link?

Comment: @Kristiyan I am unable to install it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of method MongoDB\Collection::insert() using insertOne() or insertMany() would work!